# Rich Text Editor in React Native for both android and IOS

Tags: react-native

I wanted to add Text Editor functionality in my app but I dont find any way to add it

I have used [react-native-zss-rich-text-editor](https://github.com/wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor) 
but I always get Error in react-native-webview-bridge-updated 
Error in IOS : **Duplicate Lib added**

Comment: Did you get this working? Mind sharing your solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I was able to link the module by calling react-native link after
>   installing.
>
> Make sure your link succeeded by checking (in XCode) that your project
>   has the following library under the Libraries folder:
>   React-Native-Webview-Bridge.xcodeproj. If not, add it. Then, click on
>   your project, go to the General tab, and scroll down to Linked
>   Frameworks and Libraries. Make sure libReact-Native-Webview-Bridge.a
>   is on the list. If it isn't, add it using the + sign.
>
> After the link is successful, you'll still get a bunch of duplicate
>   definition errors in iOS when trying to run from XCode (i listed it
>   above). It looks like the project is importing some libraries that
>   react-native is already importing, resulting in a conflict. I was able
>   to fix these by using the following steps:
>
> Open XCode, and make the following amendments:

1. remove #import  from RCTView.h
2. change #import "RCTBridge.h" to #import "React/RCTBridge.h" in RCTWebViewBridgeManager.m
3. change #import  to #import "RCTViewManager.h" in RCTUIManager.h
4. change #import "RCTLog.h" to #import "React/RCTLog.h" in RCTWebViewBridge.m

> I was able to run the project successfully afterwards. Hope that helps.